# Make Framed expressions fill Grid cells

Tags: formatting, grid-layouts

Given the following example, how can I make each `Framed` object to fill its `Grid` cell both vertically and horizontally?
Obviously, `Grid` calculates some cell sizes, that `Button` knows of (as andre314 has pointed out), but not `Framed`, `Pane`, `Panel`, etc. How can I reproduce the behaviour of `Button` with other constructs without relying on explicit numbers?

```
ClearAll[b, f1, f2];

b = Button[#, Background -> LightGray, ImageSize -> Full] &;
f1 = Framed[#, Background -> LightGray, RoundingRadius -> 5] &;
f2 = Framed[#, Background -> LightGray, RoundingRadius -> 5, ImageSize -> Full] &;

Grid[{{b@"321\n123", b@"123456789"}, {b@"321", SpanFromLeft}}, 
   Spacings -> {0, 0}, Frame -> None],
Grid[{{f1@"321\n123", f1@"123456789"}, {f1@"321", SpanFromLeft}}, 
   Spacings -> {0, 0}, Frame -> None],
Grid[{{f2@"321\n123", f2@"123456789"}, {f2@"321", SpanFromLeft}}, 
   Spacings -> {0, 0}, Frame -> None]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I propose a workaround, in case nobody find something better.

If you replace `Framed` by `Button` it gives :

```
Grid[{{Button["321\n123", Background -> Yellow, RoundingRadius -> 5], 
   Button["123456789", Background -> Green, 
    RoundingRadius -> 5]}, {Button["321", Background -> Cyan, 
    RoundingRadius -> 5], SpanFromLeft}}, Spacings -> {0, 0}, 
 Frame -> All, FrameStyle -> Black]
```

[image]

Comment: This is nice! I certainly want to have a general method where I can use any construct inside, not just `Button`. I wonder, what hidden option or internal property of `Button` ensures this behaviour that is missing from e.g. `Frame`? No matter of how I specify `ImageSize` within `Button`, I cannot explicitly reproduce it.

Comment: In the past, I have tried a little bit to reproduce the behaviour of Button on another object (I don't remember which one) : no success.